# include? not working rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, what I'm trying to do is test if an input has a greater than sign, but the include? isnt working. Even when I just test if the if is "true" it doesnt work. The code is below

```
if @search.select.instance_of?(Integer)
  if @search.search.include?(">")
    @gsearch = @search.search.gsub(">","")
    @results = @model.where("#{@param} > ?", @newsearch.to_i)
  else
    @results = @model.where("#{@param}": @search.search)
  end
end
```

So, first, it is testing if the "select" is an integer (it is in my tests), next it is testing if there is a ">" sign (there is, but it isnt found) Then it is displaying the results of the search. I have no idea whats wrong, and Im sorry for bad question asking, its late, and Im tired of this lol. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: No error comes up, it just shows a blank page...

Comment: Are you completely sure that this `if @search.select.instance_of?(Integer)` gives you back true? If not try using `is_a?`

Comment: Hm, youre right, but both of them return as false... I think I know  the problem (maybe?) but how do I check if an objects parameter takes in an Integer as the input?

Comment: It takes anything you give it if I an not mistakeb. But you can check using `param.class` which will tell you what class is in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
2.3.1 :001 > "asdf>".include?(">")
 => true 
2.3.1 :002 > "asdf".include?(">")
 => false
```

Seems to work to me. My guess is you need to check what `@search.search` is, and see if it actually has a `>` in it.

If it does, the only other explanation I can think of is perhaps there are multiple `>` characters with fancy unicode versions.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! And yes, the include works in other places, but it doesnt work in this ONE spot, its very weird... Oh well, Ill keep working on it. Thanks again!

Comment: hmm, are you sure `@search.search` is what you want? seems like a funny name

Comment: Yeah, its pretty much the input (shoot why didnt I name it that lol), and when I put it in, I input it as ">40"

Comment: I could add the rest of the code, if that might help find a problem?

Comment: Try adding `byebug` just before the problem line

Comment: then run it, and in the console type `@search.search` to see what it is

Comment: All is well, except for @gsearch. It should be 40 (>40 but without ">") but it returns as nil, any fixes?